# UITableViewCell Text Problem

Tags: iphone, objective-c, sdk, uitableview, background

So I am using the textLabel and detailTextLabel to add information onto my TableView cells however there is an issue.

There is a white box around both of the labels and I tried setting their backgroundColor to clearColor but that doesn't seem to work.

Any suggestions?

Comment: The way to set backgroundColor to clearColor is the right way. Maybe something wrong about how you add textLabel and detailTextLabel to a custom cell.

Answer (score 1):

By default, UITableView sets the label background colour to the table view background colour. This is presumably for optimization (it lets the label be "opaque", so no alpha blending is needed when compositing).=

There are two main fixes to this problem:

- In your UITableViewDelegate, implement -tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath: and set backgroundColor=nil and opaque=NO. (As far as I know, `nil` is generally equivalent to `[UIColor clearColor]`.)
- Override `-[UITableViewCell setSelected:animated]` and `backgroundColor` and `opaque` as above. This works because setSelected:animated: is called before the cell is first displayed, but is a bit ickier (it's called a lot).

Comment: Hey. So I did something like cell.backgroundColor = nil and cell.opaque = NO; but that actually gave my text a black background instead of the white it had before. Any suggestions?

Comment: Actually fixed it myself, did clearColor instead! Thanks for the help mate